# What would be proper query to search for key and value in ES?

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I would like what is wrong and what is not wrong in this mapping.

```
"metadata": {
  "type": "nested",
  "include_in_parent": true,
  "properties":{
    "value": {
      "fields": {
        "lower_case_sort": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "case_insensitive_sort"
        }
      },
      "properties": {
        "technical": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "key": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "value": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

The table - metadata has column 'value' where the info is and that is what I want to search against -

{"technical":[{"key": "techname22","value": "test"},{"key": "techname22","value": "red"},{"key": "techlocation","value": "usa"}],"audio": [{"key": "techname22","value": "test"},{"key": "blah","value": "blahValue"}]}

What query I need to search for technical array with value - test ?

Thank you!

Comment: what version of ES are you using, `string` as been deprecated in favor of `text` and `keyword` for a while...https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings

Comment: sounds like a `term` query as of ES today https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: I am using ES 1.7, and I cant use the newer version.

Comment: Well the term query should be there: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: Ok, but it is not finding anything with such query - 
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "full_text": "red"
    }
  }
}

Comment: is `full_text` a field? seems like it would be `metadata.value.technical`

Comment: By trying metadata.value.technical  no results.

Comment: what fields are in your index?

Comment: How can I check that? Is it mapping.json?